# Error when activating base environment for conda in arch linux

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, archlinux

I installed conda (arch linux) and wanted to update it by executing
`conda update conda` in the terminal.
This gave me the error:

```
NoBaseEnvironmentError: This conda installation has no default base environment. Use
'conda create' to create new environments and 'conda activate' to
activate environments.
```

Hence, I proceeded to execute `conda activate base`, which gave the following error message:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>
```

Running `conda init --all` (or `bash`), gives the following error:

```
# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1124, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 69, in main_subshell
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 91, in do_call
        return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/cli/main_init.py", line 33, in execute
        return initialize(context.conda_prefix, selected_shells, for_user, args.system,
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/core/initialize.py", line 118, in initialize
        run_plan_elevated(plan2)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/core/initialize.py", line 714, in run_plan_elevated
        result = subprocess_call(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/gateways/subprocess.py", line 98, in subprocess_call
        stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input=stdin)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1207, in communicate
        stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 2055, in _communicate
        input_view = memoryview(self._input)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
`$ /usr/bin/conda init --all`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
               CONDA_ROOT=/usr
           CURL_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
          LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/usr/lib/:/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-
                          openjdk/lib/server:/usr/lib/:/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/server
               LD_PRELOAD=<not set>
                     PATH=/home/my_name/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/us
                          r/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl
                          :/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>
            XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
         XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0

     active environment : None
       user config file : /home/my_name/.condarc
 populated config files : /etc/conda/condarc
          conda version : 23.1.0
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.11.3.final.0
       virtual packages : __archspec=1=x86_64
                          __glibc=2.37=0
                          __linux=6.3.3=0
                          __unix=0=0
       base environment : /usr  (read only)
      conda av data dir : /usr/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/my_name/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/my_name/.conda/envs
                          /usr/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/23.1.0 requests/2.28.2 CPython/3.11.3 Linux/6.3.3-arch1-1 arch/ glibc/2.37
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you done `pip install conda` to get `conda` installed? That is not a supported installation path

Comment: No, via AUR (cloning from git, makepkg, etc)